# How to calculate distance between two geo coordinates on earth

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe having data about the bicycle trips in Chicago. The dataframe has 6 rows: start_station_name, start_lng,  start_lat,end_station_name,  end_lng, end_lat. I want to calculate the distance between covered during a trip. I tried using

```
    library("geosphere")
     rides_2021_v2 %>% 
      mutate(ride_distance = distm(cbind(start_lng, start_lat),cbind(end_lng,end_lat), fun = distHarversine))
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `ride_distance` cannot allocate vector of size 78420.0 Gb.
```

I think the error is due to the fact that the dataframe has millions of rows of data.

Comment: It is. You either need to sample your data, or use a machine with more memory.

Comment: Isn't there any alternate way to do this? Like using any other function. I can't afford a machine with a higher memory right now. And I can't sample the data since I need to analyse the data of the whole year.

Comment: If you are analyzing the data into smaller time periods (by month, or by week), you could go through a process where you filter down to a week, run the analysis as laid out above, and then repeat the process week by week. That would avoid the issue of overloading your computer's memory with data.

Comment: Ok, I get your point but isn't there any other more optimised way to do it. Any other function which I can use? I have a laptop with decent specs. i5 10210U, 8 gb ram, 512gb ssd.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but 8 GB of RAM is definitely not going to be enough to handle millions of cases.

Comment: Ok thanks will try analyzing the data into smaller time periods.